# Grails controller not refreshing cache on change to database

Tags: caching, grails, grails-orm

I started working on a Grails project that uses Spring and Hibernate. The problem arises that when I change an entry in database with following code

```
class AlarmsController implements UserAware {
    def saveAlarm() {
        def user = DeviceUser.findById(id)
        user.field = value
        user.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

        render serialize(user) as JSON <%-- not relevant --%>
    }
}
```

where `field`, `id` and `value` are some variables that I not present and are not important. The thing gets saved in database table `DeviceUser` which I can check by manually connecting to database and executing a `SELECT` statement. Now the problem arises, that when I access `localhost:8080/api/devices/1234` which is mapped to method `show(id)`:

```
class DeviceUserController implements UserAware {
    def show(id) {
        def deviceUser = DeviceUser.where({
            id = id,
            device = device
        }).get()

        render serialize(deviceUser) as JSON
    }
}
```

the result does not get refreshed (also after executing hard refresh, that is `CTRL + F5`). I assume the content is getting cached, which indeed is, but as I googled the problem, `flush: true` should prevent getting the cached content on next call.

`serialize(content)` is a class method that converts `content` to JSON map.

---

I have tried different things like `evict(DeviceUser)`, but nothing worked. I also tried rebooting the computer after setting `user.field` to `0` (on `localhost:8080/api/devices/1234` `user.field` is always presented as to be set to `1`), but it still did not change (the value was still `1`, although in database it was `0`).

Comment: I would guess the where query is the problem. Try `id == idParam && device == deviceParam`

Comment: @andi it turned out that the `findById` was the problem. Somehow these guys that were working on project before deemed ok to have a field `device_id` which is not unique. What happened was that when I wrote to database, it saved to the first object in the database it found, that being the one with highest `id` (not `device_id`!!). But when I executed `.get()` it returned some other object, which had the same `device_id`. So i needed to make `findById` more explicit, e.g. `findByIdAndUser`. And I spent 2 days trying to solve the problem where it actually were none errors

Answer (score 0):

The question has been solved. See comments. The problem was not in cache but in some strange database layout that got succesfully debugged after printing whole tables from the database.